# Alertmanager prometheus, It doesn't sent mail alert

Tags: prometheus

First, I configure postfix null-client on server. It can send mail successfull
I configure Alertmanager:

```
notification_config {
    name: "alert_test"
    email_config {
        email: "abc@gmail.com"
    }
}
aggregation_rule {
  repeat_rate_seconds: 3600
  notification_config_name: "alert_test"
}
```

And run command:

```
./alertmanager -notification.smtp.smarthost :25 -config.file alertmanager.conf
```

It display notice:

```
ERRO[0002] Error sending email notification: starttls failed: tls: either ServerName or InsecureSkipVerify must be specified in the tls.Config  file=notifier.go line=758
```

Can you help me to fix its?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're running into X.509 validation issues.

Disable the TLS requirement, which is [turned on by default](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/).

```
# The default SMTP TLS requirement.
[ smtp_require_tls: <bool> | default = true ]
```

Comment: This works for me on Kube-Prometheus stack : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677571/alertmanagerconfig-not-sending-alerts-to-email-receiver/76748834#76748834

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `-notification.smtp.smarthost` flag to `localhost:25`. The hostname is not inferred in this case.

Comment: I try, but it display "starttsl failed: x509"

Answer (score 0):

After, I configure Postfix null-client and have account root@abc.com, I use this account to send mail successfull.
When I use together with alermanager prometheus, and use command:

```
./alertmanager -notification.smtp.smarthost 127.0.0.1:25 -config.file alertmanager.conf
```

I don't receive mail alert and it has notice:

```
> ERRO[0001] Error sending email notification: starttls failed: x509:cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs file=notifier.go line=761
```

How to fix error, thanks!